# Can we change the input_length in a trained model?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I trained the following model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(10000, 100, input_length = 10, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable = False))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True)))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2 activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x, y, epochs=10)
```

But, I got a input of length 100, while predicting.
So, i would like to know if I can change the value of input_length, according to length of the input while predicting?

If yes then how will that effect the model, or should I use encoders and decoders model?

Comment: what backend do you usE?

Comment: I am using keras on tensorflow

Comment: You can manually get out the weights and construct a new graph with 1 step.

Comment: Also consider shared layers: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers. Then reuse the embedding layer with `input_length=100`.
Another option is simply to split the test input to 10 batches and concatenate the results afterwards.

Comment: Thats also a good example: https://keras.io/examples/lstm_seq2seq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have found

```
model._layers[0].batch_input_shape = (None,500)
new_model = model_from_json(model.to_json())
new_model.summary()
```